# While making the bid in any one console i am getting this error in the cordapp-auction project

Tags: corda

```
E 12:59:13+0530 [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_D ON PUBLIC.TRADE_STATES(OUTPUT_INDEX, TRANSACTION_ID) VALUES (0, '26EF53AD8C3CC7A99344B65B8469655FE9FE8ABB8DF98E1FEAC32425E122BFE4', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into trade_states (amount, auctionReference, bidder, itemOwner, linear_id, output_index, transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-194] {}
E 14:58:49+0530 [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_C ON PUBLIC.VAULT_STATES(OUTPUT_INDEX, TRANSACTION_ID) VALUES (0, '6FA36D1F62B0B20F9A4903AA175655E0D567116DB63D802DC7A6CB6E2C3EE3AE', 14)"; SQL statement:
insert into vault_states (consumed_timestamp, contract_state_class_name, lock_id, lock_timestamp, notary_name, recorded_timestamp, state_status, output_index, transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-194] {}
E 14:58:49+0530 [Node thread-1] internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] {}
```

**ok when i am trying to make the bid from anyone console it is showing this error**

2nd error

```
list is empty
```

when i am trying to close the auction

the project is from github (https://github.com/vardan10/cordapp-auction)

anyone can help me with this errors

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we will not be able to identify the issue with the above information. We would need more details for debug.

Furthermore, please refer to this official repository https://github.com/corda/samples for cordapp sample reference.